# How to stop the client IP address getting lost in a Cloudflare/Docker/NGINX/LAMP site?

Tags: php, nginx, docker, cloudflare

The problem is the PHP field `$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']` is not being set in my following site structure, how should I correct this?

*Static IP containers on a Docker bridge network (on a host behind cloudflare) named 'back':*

1. NGINX running in container (172.24.02)
2. Apache + PHP in container (172.24.0.3)

**nginx.conf:**

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://172.24.0.3;
}
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

echo('HTTP_CLIENT_IP: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']);
echo('<br>HTTP_X_FORWARDE‌​D_FOR'.$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDE‌​D_FOR']);
echo('<br>REMOTE_ADDR'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo('<br>HTTP_X_FORWARDED'.$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']);
echo('<br>HTTP_FORWARDED'.$_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']);
echo('<br>HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'.$_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']);

?>
```

Running the above yields:

```
HTTP_CLIENT_IP: 
HTTP_X_FORWARDE‌​D_FOR: 
REMOTE_ADDR: 172.24.0.2
HTTP_X_FORWARDED: 
HTTP_FORWARDED: 
HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR:
```

Comment: How do you have Nginx and Apache configured to work together?

Comment: HTTP_CLIENT_IP isn't a standard header, REMOTE_ADDR is the standard for the IP, but in proxy situations, you'll need to set a header.  Why not print out all the headers `print_r($_SERVER)` rather than trying to print ones that don't necessarily align with the headers being defined.

Comment: @Devon Apache is running on port 80 in one container, nginx simply forwards requests to it with the above config to pass headers on. I'm going to try your suggestion re printing out the whole variable

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Devon for making the suggestion of printing out the $_SERVER variable, turns out the following fields had the client IP in them:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
```

The first gave the `client IP`, the second gave `client IP, cloudflare IP`